# Why does Python output an empty list when it should have output a list of URLs?

Tags: python, list

I ran the script below to grab text from a Pastebin text file and turn it into a list. Unfortunately, it's printing an empty list. Can anyone help me diagnose why this is the case? Thank you!

### Command typed:

```
script.py -id 049YJMdV
```

### Script

```
import requests, re, argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-id','--id', required=False)
args = vars(parser.parse_args())
id = args['id']

link = "https://web.archive.org/web/20150611011149/http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i={}".format(id)
data = []

links = requests.get(link).text
urls = re.findall(r'https?://[^\s<>"]+[|www\.^\s<>"]+', links)


print(data)
```

### Output

```
[]
```

Comment: there is nothing assigned to `data`, have you tried `print(urls)`?

Comment: Appreciate it! Yes, I tried `print(urls)`, and it worked. But I would still ideally like to have the list equal to a variable so I can use it later. How can I go about turning the contents of the text file (the `link` variable) into a list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The array is getting printed empty because you're defining

```
data = []
```

without actually appending anything to it at all. Therefore, its behaving as expected because nothing has been added to it and prints an empty list.

Also, you have the id as not required. However, it will throw an exception since no id is provided in the url. Would double check that as well.

Comment: Thank you for your invaluable help. How can I go about turning the contents of the text file (the `link` variable) into a list?

Comment: I mean if its a string with spaces between words you can use the `.split` functionality by spaces. This does not look like you're reading a file? it looks like its a get request rather than actually reading locally from a file.